# Font Error when using pslatex and gnuplot

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

I have a very persistent problem. I am creating a figure using gnuplot with pslatex terminal. Then I use Latex to create the .dvi (using the figure), then dvips to create the .ps and finally ps2pdf to create the .pdf. On the last step, I get the following error:

GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Error: Font Renderer Plugin ( FreeType ) return code = -1

This causes the font in the figure to come out too large. Basically, I cannot control the font anymore from within gnuplot.

I have installed a fixed version of FreeType (http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=692948) but it didn't help. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! That bug is from 2 years ago. Are you sure you had the buggy version installed in the first place? If this problem occurs with a minimal example, it might be but if it is specific to this particular figure, I doubt freetype had anything to do with it. In any case, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the issue.